# Return array length from receiver function

Tags: go

I've an array as:

```golang
// Stock file
type Stock []StockLine
```

And want to get the length of this array as:

```golang
//Records returns number of records in the stock file
func (s *Stock) Records() int {
    return len(*s)
}
```

But the returned output looks to be address instead of the length, i got:

```sh
0x1154420
```

Minimum running exampple:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stock []StockLine

type StockLine struct {
    Resource string
    Color    string
    Style    string
    Size     string
    Quantity  int64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    stock := Stock{}
    stock = append(stock, StockLine{
        Resource :"Shirt",
            Color    :"Blue",
            Style    :"Modern",
            Size     :"XL",
            Quantity :10,
    })
    
    fmt.Printf("%v", stock.Records)
    
}

//Records returns number of records in the stock file
func (s *Stock) Records() int {
    return len(*s)
}
```

How can I return the proper length?

Comment: That is correct. Please show a [mre].

Comment: You need to clarify if you are looking for an array or a slice. An array has a fixed length while a slice has both a length and a capacity. See [here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fmt.Printf("%v", stock.Records)` will print the address of the function; if you want the result you need to [add brackets](https://play.golang.org/p/c6M3RY59FXl) so it is called i.e. `fmt.Printf("%v", stock.Records())`